# "Save You Money" or "Save Your Money"?

Tags: word-choice

> The discount is here to save you money.
>
> The discount is here to save your money.

Which one of them is correct?

Comment: You are welcome to save me money. If you want to save my money instead, I first have to ask from what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct. In each case, *money* is the direct object of *save*. The money is saved.

In the first example, *you* is the indirect object. *You* are the beneficiary of the action. it could be rephrased to read *The discount here saves money **for** you.*

In the second example, *money* is still the direct object, and there is no expressed indirect object. But the beneficiary of the action is implied by the adjective *your* which modifies *money*.

The former is likely more common and flows better. The phrase *save your money* is often used in circumstances when a person is being urged to spend no money.

> The item is junk. Save your money. [meaning *don't buy it*]

Answer (score 0):

Under the guise of *money* being an indirect object...

> The discount is here to save you money.

Possible variations...

> The discount here saves you money.
>   The discount is to save you money.
>   The discount saves you money.

Comment: Why isn't the latter accepted?

Comment: I don't know if the latter is accepted, however I clarified my answer: that the pronoun (direct object) saves money (indirect).

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid. Possible usage for the verb [to save](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/save) are...

> 1: intransitive
>    **Jesus saves** (non-specific, which allows for [jocular misinterpretation](http://www.tshirtsunited.com/catalogue/tshirts/all/jesussavesbutrooney.html))
>
> 2: transitive
>    **Jesus saves sinners**
>
> 3: ditransitive
>    **Jesus saves sinners going to hell** (with the gerund/noun *going to hell* as a "secondary object")

In OP's case, *saves you money* is a ditransitive usage. The "beneficiary" is ***you***, the "secondary object" is ***money***.

Note that the secondary object can be either something ***preserved*** (money) or something ***prevented***/made unnecessary (going to hell). OP's alternative *saves **your** money* is thus a transitive usage where the single object *your money* is *preserved, retained, not wasted*.

---

Although I said both versions are *valid*, that doesn't mean they're equally likely. OP's first version is far more common, as evidenced by the fact that Google Books claims [19,900 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20saved%20my%20money%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22this%20will%20save%20you%20money%22&tbm=bks) for ditransitive *"this will save **you** money"*, but [only 9 instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20saved%20my%20money%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22this%20will%20save%20your%20money%22&tbm=bks) of *"this will save **your** money"*.